# Invalid Redirect URI Deezer OAuth

Tags: oauth, deezer

I am getting the Invalid Redirect URI while trying to authenticate. This is the first step to authenticating on the guide and I have literally copy-pasted the code into my browser and subbed in my Application Domain and Application ID and it says Please enter a valid redirect_URI. `https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=MyAppID&redirect_uri=MyRedirectURI`

Comment: Has your redirect URI the same domain than your application? The problem could come from that.

Comment: My redirect URI is ExampleURI:// and the application domain is ExampleURI://Deezer. Is this a problem? Because it works with GitHub and Spotify

Comment: Yes, your application domain and redirect URI don't seem correct, the problem should be that. Can you try with well-formatted URI?

Comment: I don't think it matters what my application uri is because even when I paste it into chrome it doesn't work whereas with github it would ask me if I wanted to open my application.  This is on desktop bte

Comment: even if i put htpp://google.com as my redirect uri it doesnt work

Comment: Hello. You should contact the Deezer developers' support : http://developers.deezer.com/support. They will be able to help you with configuring your app so as not to get this error again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I found out that unlike any other music streaming service, Deezer does not allow (or it's a bug) redirect uris that

- contain a port like localhost:9000/deezer/callback
- have a subdomain like cheapuri.noip.me
- I guess co.uk then won't work either

It seems that the only thing that is working are "normal" uris like api.com. 
The way I work around this when developing:

Let Deezer redirect you to some non existing uri, then change the uri in the browser bar.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that the redirect_uri in your /oauth request URL matches exactly that which is referenced in your oauth configuration/whitelist settings for Deezer.

Even the smallest difference like `http` vs `https` or including `wwww.`, etc. can throw an error. You might find some of the tips in this [OAuth Troubleshooting Guide](https://developers.miro.com/docs/troubleshooting-oauth20) helpful for other common OAuth errors to check, too!

The first item in that guide covers some common invalid redirect errors.